# how to add an audio hal to android device just with root access?

Tags: android, audio, android-source, aidl, hal

I want to create an [audio hal](https://source.android.com/devices/audio) for Android to have a virtual microphone on the Android device.

I'm confused about applying hal on an Android device.

Can we apply our hal without making a custom ROM on the Android device?
Or can we apply our own audio hal with using the root commands?
Another point is that as I noticed in the new versions of Android (11 and 12) new features ([AIDL](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/aidl/aidl-hals), [APEX](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/apex)) have been added to implement and apply Hal.
Is there a source to get acquainted with them and can audio hal be implemented and applied using them?
Finally, if there is an example to understand the production cycle and the application of hal, I would be very happy to let you know.